# How to get library version in autoconf?

Tags: shared-libraries, autoconf

I need to know the version of the library `libraptor2` installed on the computer.

Preferably I need to determine it in `configure` script.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
RAPTOR_VERSION=`pkg-config --modversion raptor2`
```